# Magento invalid backend name error

Tags: apache, magento, zend-framework

I am trying to run a local copy of my website but everytime I run it gives me this error. I tried to look after other similar answer but could not find a relevant answer.

I am using Macbook, XAMPP and Magento 1.8

This is the error displayed

```
Invalid backend name []

Trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ameb_prod/lib/Zend/Cache.php(137): Zend_Cache::throwException('Invalid backend...')
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ameb_prod/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/TwoLevels.php(135): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('', Array, true, true)
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ameb_prod/lib/Zend/Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_TwoLevels->__construct(Array)
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ameb_prod/lib/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('TwoLevels', Array, true, true)
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ameb_prod/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(137): Zend_Cache::factory('Varien_Cache_Co...', 'TwoLevels', Array, Array, true, true, true)
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ameb_prod/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1354): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->__construct(Array)
#6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ameb_prod/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/cache', Array)
#7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ameb_prod/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(401): Mage::getModel('core/cache', Array)
#8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ameb_prod/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(295): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCache(Array)
#9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ameb_prod/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(337): Mage_Core_Model_App->baseInit(Array)
#10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ameb_prod/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ameb_prod/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

Comment: can you add you local.xml to the question ?

Comment: It seems like a custom module. Can you give more details?